# Parsing a JSON string from within a TXT file

Tags: javascript, json

I'm wanting to have the user pick a file which is then read and then parsed into a JSON in order to be added to their localStorage. The issue is that reading from the file results in every single character being read as a key, however pasting the JSON string directly into the function results in the string being properly parsed.

Is anyone able to tell me what why the file method isn't working?

Here's the code that reads the file (This results in every single character becoming a key within LocalStorage).

```
<h1>Import/Export</h1>
        <button id="export">Export</button>
        <br><br>
        <input type="file" name="inputfile" id="inputfile">
        <br><br>
        <!-- <textarea id="input" placeholder="Paste the contents of the exported TXT file here"></textarea> -->
        <br>
        <br>
        <button id="import">Import</button>
        <pre id="output" style="display: none;"></pre>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById('inputfile').addEventListener('change', function() {
                var fr=new FileReader();
                fr.onload=function(){
                    document.getElementById('output').textContent=fr.result;
                    console.log(fr.result)
                    // Read the JSON
                    var data = JSON.parse(fr.result);
                    console.log(data)
                    Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k) {
                        localStorage.setItem(k, data[k]);
                    });
                }
                fr.readAsText(this.files[0])
            })
        </script>
```

Here's the code that just works either within a function or running it in the console:

```
var data = JSON.parse("JSON STRING GOES HERE");
    console.log(data)
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k) {
        localStorage.setItem(k, data[k]);
    });
```

Comment: It works fine for me. What's in your txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note that **localStorage key/value pairs can only be strings**. (See [this StackOverflow answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219953/how-is-localstorage-different-from-indexeddb) for more information about this).

There are two issues here:

**First**, assuming your text file containing a JSON string looks like this (data taken from [JSON Placeholder](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder/master/data.json)):

```json
"{\"posts\":[{\"userId\":1,\"id\":1,\"title\":\"sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit\",\"body\":\"quia et suscipit\\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto\"},{\"userId\":1,\"id\":2,\"title\":\"qui est esse\",\"body\":\"est rerum tempore vitae\\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla\"}]}"
```

You'll notice from your `console.log(data)` that your JSON string is only partly parsed (the `posts` array objects are still stringified). If you parse the result twice, you get the `posts` array logged properly as JavaScript rather than a string:

```js
var data = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(fr.result));
```

Of course, depending on how deeply nested your JSON data is, you may prefer to search for or write your own function that recursively parses the JSON string.

**Second**, as I mentioned above, localStorage can only accept keys and values that are strings. Even if you add the double parse as I suggest above, *you're attempting to set a JavaScript **object** as a value in localStorage, not a **string***.

So, in your `forEach` loop, when setting the data in localStorage, you have to re-stringify it:

```js
Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k) {
  localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(k), JSON.stringify(data[k]));
});
```

Of course, then you have to do further work when pulling the data from localStorage to parse *that* JSON string into an object to use its values. Depending on the complexity of the data you're reading/storing, you might consider using IndexedDB or a more traditional database instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it working by parsing it twice when reading the JSON into `data`. However, it didn't work with stringifying when setting the item. I removed those and it worked! `localStorage.setItem(k, data[k]);` and `var data = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(fr.result));`